# Using a non-SSL subdomain alongside an SSL root domain?

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, domain

I've been looking through other similar questions but so far none of the answers I've found have worked.

I'm trying to use my root domain, for now let's say "domain.net" for my own content with SSL. So far, that works along with SSL. The problem starts after I try to use a subomain on the same system, for a server panel without SSL.
Google Domains is my provider. So far, I've tried a CNAME DNS entry pointing "sub.domain.net" to "domain.net," then after that didn't work a second A entry pointing "sub.domain.net" to the same IP address as "domain.net." The best result I could get from either attempts was my router's info page would show up when connecting to "sub.domain.net."

Here is my current Apache config (my domain name is edited to "domain.net" to keep it private):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.net
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName domain.net
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/resume"
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/pterodactyl/public"
  ServerName sub.domain.net
  AllowEncodedSlashes On
  php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
  php_value post_max_size 100M
  <Directory "/var/www/pterodactyl/public">
    AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What could I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this question is exactly answerable as is, however I can make some statements which may help you solve your issues.

When it comes to web pages and DNS, all DNS does is resolve a domain name to an IP address.  For a subdomain you can use a CNAME which goes to a domain, or you can enter an IP address directly - if in doubt an IP address is better.  My point here, is that as long as the DNS points to the IP address of your web server, the way the DNS is programmed will not influence the page the web server shows.

If you are hosting your website inside your network you may have a problem with the external IP address and internal IP addresses being different, and unless your router handles something called "Hairpin NAT", you may need to use some trickery like adding entries into your hosts file to override the DNS settings and point to the internal IP address of your web server.

I suspect, however, that your website is not hosted outside your home network.  If this is the case and you are getting your routers home page, it is likely there is a local DNS issue - you should try from devices not connected to your LAN and see what happens.   My guess is your router has a "search domain" or domain name set in your router which is the same as the domain of the website you are trying to host and that is confusing the DNS system on your LAN.  You can likely resolve this issue in the router by changing it to "intranet"